# R: get corresponding value from another data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and here and I need some help to structure my data.

I have two data sets:
One of them is a long format within subjects data set which is large and looks a little bit like this:

```
long.format <- data.frame(subject.no = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), condition = c("prime", "prime", "prime", "prime", "control", "control","control","control"), response = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0)) 

     subject.no condition response
>1          1     prime        1
>2          1     prime        1
>3          1     prime        1
>4          1     prime        0
>5          2   control        1
>6          2   control        1
>7          2   control        1
>8          2   control        0
```

The other one is already in wide format and looks like this

```
wide.format <- data.frame(subject = c(1, 2), age = c(26,27), gender = c("m","f")) 

     subject age gender
>1       1  26      m
>2       2  27      f
```

The only thing I want to do now is to get the value in "condition" (and only this!) from the long format data frame to the corresponding subject in the wide data frame by adding a new column in the wide data frame (by using the columns subject.no and subject, respectively).

So the final data frame should look like this:

```
wide.format.aim <- data.frame(subject = c(1, 2), age = c(26,27), gender = c("m","f"), condition = c("prime","control")) 

      subject age gender condition
>1       1  26      m     prime
>2       2  27      f   control
```

I've tried merging but this ended up with a long format data frame added with the information from the wide format data frame... but I want it the other way around...

This is what I've tried:

```
test.it <- merge(x=wide.format, y=long.format[,c("subject.no", "condition")], all.x=T, by.x="subject", by.y="subject.no")
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried merging (sorry this is with the real variable names)
test.it <- merge(x=data.values, y=data[,c("subject_nr", "Bedingung")], all.x=T, by.x="vp.list", by.y="subject_nr") - but this didn't work (if you like I can explain what happened in more words...)

Comment: alright! hope this is easy to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interested merging the unique values from `long.format[,c("subject.no", "condition")]`:

```
unique(long.format[,c("subject.no", "condition")])
#  subject.no condition
#1          1     prime
#5          2   control
```

You can merge using those values

```
merge(x = wide.format,
      y = unique(long.format[,c("subject.no", "condition")]),
      by.x = "subject",
      by.y = "subject.no")
#  subject age gender condition
#1       1  26      m     prime
#2       2  27      f   control
```

Comment: so it's only been one simple word "unique()" on the right place... It did work, so thank you very much!

Comment: @Mathias You could have thrown a `unique()` around your existing code, as well, but it seems more efficient to merge on the unique subset rather than to merge first then filter out duplicates.